# Favicon size in browser tab

Tags: website-design, html, favicon

I am creating a website and I have the logo. When I insert the logo in the HTML basically as a fav icon in the tab, it appears so small. The question can any body help to increase its size so it can be big and clear.

Comment: If you had your icon or a screenshot of the problem in your question it may be easier for us to help you :-)

Comment: Very unsure this is a graphic design question

Comment: Related: [What can the favicon of a website be based on if the website doesn't have a logo?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/94124/23061)

Answer (score 3):

Favicon is 16v16 px for web browsers. You cannot increase the size.

However, you can still set your favicon to multiple resolutions in HTML (32x32,64x64,128x128).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my logo comparing to other logos is very small in the tab even though it is big in reality?

Comment: A favicon in a browser tab renders at 16x16 even if the favicon is set at a larger size.

Comment: I will try the size you told me and I will reply to you if it is okay.

Comment: It is the same my friend

Comment: No matter what, your favicon in a web bowser tab will be 16x16. You can't change that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should stretch the entire logo till it hits the borders of your canvas. Thay way you're sure you've exploited the maximum space and therefore made the icon bigger.